# how to display few records from a database in dataviewgrid control in c#?

Tags: c#, ado.net

suppose i am having a database table with 20 records and of that i want to display only 10 records in the dataviewgrid control, how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT TOP 10 * FROM (
    SELECT TOP 20 * FROM MyTable ORDER BY MyID ASC
  ) AS NewTbl ORDER BY MyID DESC
) AS NewTbl2 ORDER BY MyID  ASC
```

This selects records 11-20. If you want to select records 6-15 just change 20 to 15.
20 is the "last record to select" and 10 is the number of records before and up to 20.

**Edit** (After your comment about having all rows in a DataSet):

```
var newDS = new DataSet();
newDS.Tables.Add(oldDSWithAllRows.Tables["YourTableName"].Clone());

foreach (DataRow myDataRow in oldDSWithAllRows.Tables["YourTableName"].Rows)
{
  if (/* Your criteria */)
  {
    newDS.Tables["YourTableName"].ImportRow(myDataRow);
  }
}

myDataGridView.DataSource = newDS;
```

Comment: can you please translate the above code in C#? i am not familiar with vb.net

Comment: i am a newbie and hence not familiar with statements like 
foreach (DataRow myDataRow in oldDSWithAllRows.Rows) 
so if possible can u plz explain in words what that statement does so that i can try to do it in my own way.
thx in advance.

Comment: The foreach loop takes all rows in your current ´DataSet´ and loops through them one by one. Much like a for loop but without an indexer.

Comment: if i am not wrong, what u r trying to suggest is that i create a new table in my dataset and then whichever rows i want from my old table (in the same dataset), i copy those rows to the new table and then fill the datagridview with this new table.

Comment: That is exactly what I suggest.

Comment: well, i tried doing that but i am getting the error "This row already belongs to another table". ne solns for dis????

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You can use DataTable.ImportRow. Changed the code to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Select only the 10 records you want.

In SQL use the `TOP` clause:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM myTable
```

Comment: actually, i have a DataSet object consisting of the entire table and from this dataset object i want to take out any 10 records, depending on a certain condition and put them into the dataviewgrid.

Comment: You can't do that directly on the DataSet/DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

use [DataTable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.datatable.select%28VS.80%29.aspx)

usage:

```
dataSet1.Tables[0].Select("Id>5");
```

or, better, `DataView` with a `RowFilter`, example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter%28VS.80%29.aspx)

you can set tha `DataGridView.DataSource` to this `DataView`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the latest version of C# you could filter your source with LINQ:

```
// change Skip to 10 to page through
var filtered = mydatasource.Skip(0).Take(10);
```

This assumes you've returned your SQL data as an `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: i am using visual studio 2005, so i guess, won't be able to implement there.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have the following table

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
int counter = 1;
dt.Columns.Add("ID");
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
{
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["ID"] = i;
dr["Name"] = string.Format("Name{0}", i);
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

You can bind the grid this way:

```
this.GridView1.DataSource = dt.AsEnumerable().Take(10);
this.GridView1.DataBind();
```

but:
this can work if you did the following:
-Add two template fields to the gridview
-Add the following function to the code behind page:

```
protected object GetColumnValue(object Row,string columnName)
        {
            DataRow dr = Row as DataRow;
            return dr[columnName];
        }
```

Edit the DataBindings of the fields of the gridview to bind this way:

```
GetColumnValue(Container.DataItem,"ID") //for the first Field
GetColumnValue(Container.DataItem,"Name") //for the second field
```